# How i can Focus UI Elements in Windows Store Apps?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

im creating an Windows Store App, and i want to focus the Textbox of my PopDialog.

```
 GroupName = new TextBox();
 GroupName.Width = 400;
 GroupName.Height =35;
 GroupName.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
 GroupName.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
 GroupName.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Programmatic);
 Content.Children.Add(GroupName);
```

Also i need to focus the Button, so if the User pushes enter the Button gets activated.

```
 Button create = new Button();
 create.Content = "Erstellen";
 create.Focus(FocusState.Pointer);
 create.Click += AddGroup;
 Btnpanel.Children.Add(create);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are meaning that you want to bring up the "soft" keyboard manually then I do not think that is possible.  There is keyboard system that manages that user experience and can't be initiated manually however if you would like to register to be notified when a user brings up the keyboard that is possible.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpane.aspx

In that case you can attach to the onHiding function and use that to initiate the submission.

Answer (score 0):

1. Giving focus to a textfield will show the keyboard
2. If you put the textbox in a form with a submit button, enter will be automatically trigger the submit button without any extra code.

So the trick is, force focus into your text box which is in a form with a submit button, and all should be good.